# Show $\int_{\partial \mathbb{D}} \log\lvert x-z\rvert dz \to \int_{\partial \mathbb{D}} \log\lvert y-z\rvert dz$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $y\in \partial\mathbb{D}$ where $\mathbb{D}$ is the unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Is there a way to prove that
$$
\lim_{\substack{x\to y \\ x\in \mathbb{D}}}\int_{\partial \mathbb{D}} \log\lvert x-z\rvert \,\mathrm{d}{z} = \int_{\partial \mathbb{D}} \log\lvert y-z\rvert \,\mathrm{d}{z}
$$

Thanks in advance for any help! I tried a direct approach which didn't work. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: @mathworker21 I tried that too and didn't get anywhere. Can you give any more details?

Answer (score 1):

Note that by symmetry $\int_{\partial \mathbb{D}} \log |x-z|dx$ just depends on $|x|$. Therefore, we just need to show $\int_{\partial \mathbb{D}} \log |r-z|dz \to \int_{\partial \mathbb{D}} \log |1-z|dz$ as $r \to 1$. Wolfram says all of these integrals are $0$.

Comment: How did you get the inequality? (Thank you for the help btw)

Comment: I can't justify it. It just feels right. A mixture of continuity and casework on whether $z$ is close to $y$ might work.

Comment: @MathUser_NotPrime is the inequality true?

Comment: I tried proving it for a while but couldn't quite get it to work

Comment: @MathUser_NotPrime ok yea, I think the inequality was false. I updated my answer. To show that the integrals are 0, maybe multiply by $2$ and expand out the square?